# Defining custom Mako tool with Cherrpy.Tool() failing

Tags: python, cherrypy, mako

I am attempting to define my on custom Mako loader in my cherrpy server via the following in my `server.py`:

```
from my.path.templating import MakoLoader
from HandleEvent import HandleEvent

cherrypy.tools.mako = cherrypy.Tool('on_start_resource', MakoLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

root = HandleEvent()

conf = { '/' : { 'request.dispatch' : cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()}}

app = cherrypy.tree.mount(root, '/', conf)
```

I then try to use the custom mako loader as a decorator on my `HandleEvent` class as shown:

```
  class HandleEvent(object):
        exposed = True

    @cherrypy.tools.mako(template="template.html")
    def GET(self, **urlParams):
        return 'It worked!'
```

However when I try to start the server I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cherryd", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('CherryPy==3.1.2', 'cherryd')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 461, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1194, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.1.2-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/cherryd", line 95, in <module>
    options.imports)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.1.2-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/cherryd", line 15, in start
    exec "import %s" % i
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/my/path/server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from my.path.HandleEvent import http_methods_allowed
  File "/var/my/path/HandleEvent.py", line 63, in <module>
    class handleEvent(object):
  File "/var/my/path/HandleEvent.py", line 76, in HandleEvent
    @cherrypy.tools.mako(template="template.html")
AttributeError: 'Toolbox' object has no attribute 'mako'
```

I am not sure why this happening as I have defined this custom loader in this manner before. Any insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My import of my `HandleEvent` Class needed to come after I assigned the custom Mako loader to `cherrypy.tools.mako`. So the correct code is as follows:

```
from my.path.templating import MakoLoader

cherrypy.tools.mako = cherrypy.Tool('on_start_resource', MakoLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

# The import should come here
from HandleEvent import HandleEvent
root = HandleEvent()

conf = { '/' : { 'request.dispatch' : cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()}}

app = cherrypy.tree.mount(root, '/', conf)
```